# sscanf casting warning c

Tags: c, scanf

The program's purpose is to get as an input a string containing numbers and white spaces then split the string with strtok and insert every number in an array. 
Lastly , from the array i send the numbers to the function checkPowerOfTwo which determines if the number is a power of two and prints a string with the calculation.

The warning says : `passing argument 1 of 'sscanf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|`

The warning happen on both of the lines containing sscanf . 
Any ideas of how I can resolve these warnings ? 
My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkPowerOfTwo(int x);
int main()
{
    int exp,size,*numbers,sum=0;
    char term,*str=NULL,*token;


    printf("Enter size of input:");
    if(scanf("%d%c", &size, &term) != 2 || term != '\n'){
        printf("Invalid Size\n");
        return 0;
    } if(size<=0){
        printf("Invalid size\n");
        return 0;
    } else{
        numbers=(int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+1) + (size-1)*sizeof(char));
        if(numbers==NULL||str==NULL){
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            return 0;
        } //else{
            //printf("Memory allocated\n");
        //}
        printf("Enter numbers:");
        fgets (str, sizeof(int)*(size+1) + (size-1), stdin);
        //printf("%s",str);
        token=strtok(str," ");
        while(token!=NULL){
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            //printf("%s\n",token);
            numbers[i]=(int)token;
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j =0;j<size;j++)
    {
    exp=checkPowerOfTwo(numbers[j]);
    if (exp>=0){
        int x;
        sscanf((int)numbers[j],"%d",&x);
        printf("The number %d is a power of 2: %d=2^%d\n",x,x,exp);
        sum+=exp;
    }
    }
    printf("Total exponent sum is %d",sum);
        free(numbers);
        free(str);
}

int checkPowerOfTwo(int n)
{
   int x;
   int exponent=0;
   sscanf((int)n,"%d",&x);
   //printf("checking number %d\n",x);
   if (x==0){
        return -1;
   } if  (x==1){
      return 0;
   }
   while( x != 1)
   {
      if(x % 2 != 0){
         return -1;
      }
      x /= 2;
      exponent++;
   }
   return exponent;

}
```

I tried to use the casting to (int) in both sscanf lines but the warning remains.

Comment: The statement `sscanf((int)n,"%d",&x);` needs a *string* as its first argument. The function behaves like `scanf`but, like `fscanf`, the *source* to be scanned must be given as the first argument.

Comment: It seems your [mcve] could be a lot more minimal.

Comment: On an unrelated note, casting a variable to the exact same type as the variable already is, is kind of pointless.

Comment: And why do you use `sscanf` here to begin with? To get an integer value from an integer variable? I'm very interested in your reasoning here.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me im a begginer in c .. recollecting my thoughts  , will edit post after im done

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which extracts an unknown number of integers from a string.

It does not use `strtok` but works by advancing a buffer pointer past each item that was successfully scanned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    char input[256];

    puts("Enter some numbers on one line:");
    if(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) {
        puts("Error in input");
        exit(1);
    }

    int num;
    int len;
    char *buf = input;

    puts("The numbers are:");
    while(sscanf(buf, "%d%n", &num, &len) == 1) {
        if(!isspace(buf[len])) {
            puts("Error in input");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("num=%d\n", num);
        buf += len;
    }
}
```

Program sessions:

```
Enter some numbers on one line:
123 456 789
The numbers are:
num=123
num=456
num=789

Enter some numbers on one line:
123a 456
The numbers are:
Error in input
```